# Can multiple spark tasks run with single core?

Tags: apache-spark

I ran spark code with one executor and one VCore. The Dataframe was repartitioned into 25 partitions. I called mapPartitions method with code to make some REST calls within the mapPartitions. When I looked up the stage in the Spark UI I was surprised that the 25 tasks were running parallel with 1vcore. This was even confirmed at the REST endpoint end.

I am wondering how 25 tasks can run with just 1vcore:

1> Is this concurrency using threading

2> How to know the limit of concurrency if these are concurrent calls

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the Spark UI , where you saw 25 parallel tasks ? and also your executor conifgurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sanket9394 It turned out that the YARN UI was showing 1 VCore because of this bug: https://jira.pnda.io/browse/PNDA-4006

When I looked at the Spark UI executor page it showed 25 VCores. So it was a false positive